# How to increase Java Heap Memory for CMD 6.1.1.76

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

**How to increase Java Heap Memory for CMD 6.1.1.76 ?**

I think these are no longer valid methods:

http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/java-heap-exception-when-using-sencha-cmd/#.VxQIauMrJTY

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?251529-Java-Heap-Size

**I'm getting a Java heap exception when running**

> sencha app build

**specifically while slicing images (I don't want to skip this)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to edit **sencha.cfg** file which is located in your Cmd folder.
If you are on Windows - most probably here:

```
C:\Users\<user>\bin\Sencha\Cmd\6.1.1.76
```

In it, you will find the part with JVM startup arguments:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# These are the JVM startup arguments. The primary things to tweak are the JVM
# heap sizes.
# java.awt.headless=true - required to make phantomjs (used by theme slicer)
#                          work in headless environments

# cmd.jvm.args=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8888,suspend=n -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -Djava.awt.headless=true
cmd.jvm.args=-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true
```

You can find more info about configuration files in the [Sencha Cmd Docs](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_advanced.html#Configuration_Files).

**EDIT:** From Cmd 6.5.0 this no longer works. You will have to use _JAVA_OPTIONS

```
# On previous versions, this file provided a way to specify the cmd.jvm.* properties
# to control the execution of the JVM. To accommodate all possible execution scenarios
# support for these properties has been removed in favor of using the _JAVA_OPTIONS
# environment variable.
```

Comment: You don't have to (and should not) use _JAVA_OPTIONS, except as a prefix to running an individual command. As of 6.5.0, you can edit the `sencha.vmoptions` file in the Sencha Cmd install dir. Unfortunately, this can't be set on an app-by-app basis.

Answer (score 0):

for new versions of sencha cmd (7.1+)
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAXLP.png)

you might need to increase Xms and Xmx more (**please, don't exaggerate here**)

For me, I have `-Xms2048 -Xmx8192`

close your bash/terminal and start it again over