# Extjs 6 getting Java heap space error while build

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have upgraded application from ExtJS5 to ExtJS 6.
While building the application it is giving java heap space error.
I have tried setting _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1g but no help.
Also tried increasing memory in .vmoptions file in cmd.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems like setting _JAVA_OPTIONS is available since 6.5.0. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36956140/8778804
Could you please tell us which sencha cmd version you are using?

Comment: I m using sencha cmd 6.5.2 No jre version