# ExtJS CMD 6.7.x very, very, very slow

Tags: javascript, performance, extjs, build, sencha-cmd

I have a project with 5 remote packages and 3 local packages, this project is a Maven project, the build of the whole project takes 17 minutes, the Sencha build lasts 13 minutes out of 17, in the 3 local projects there are 5 View.js files.

Is it possible that the build of 5 javascript takes 13 minutes?

Where can I investigate?

Comment: Usually it should not take that long... you can try to give sencha cmd more memory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682753/how-to-increase-java-heap-memory-for-cmd-6-1-1-76 If this won't improve your situation, try to upgrade to a later version of sencha cmd. On the other hand, their are many factors (os, jvm, package complexity) which can slow down your build, depending what you are doing exactly. You can also try to build each package individually, in order to find the root cause.

Comment: If you're using the new [open tooling](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/guides/getting_started/open_tooling.html) for Sencha Cmd, and you still have Java installed, that could also be affecting perf... once I removed Java from my system and did a complete rebuild of `package-lock.json`, my builds have seen a good perf gain.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't use 'open-tooling' yet.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with ExtJS and Sencha CMD 6.7 for multiple months and there I used apps with about 20 packages (local and remote). I didn't had such a performance issue, but I know that Sencha CMD can use a lot of memory, so I would at first increase the memory in the  sencha.vmoptions (location: C:\Users\Foo\bin\Sencha\Cmd\6.7...) file.

Additionally you have to keep in mind that a high amount of package files in the local Sencha repository increases the memory usage. I would periodically clean up your local repository, by deleting the packages in the repo folder (C:\Users\Foo\bin\Sencha\Cmd\repo or ~/Sencha/Cmd/repo). You can delete here everything except of the (hidden) folder .meta, which should not be removed - otherwise your repo is broken.
At least for me a cleanup decreased the memory usage by about 2 GB, but I had a lot of packages (and versions).

In general such a long time for the build is not normal and I would check the memory usage in first hand.

Comment: Hi, on my machine I allocated 2GB of memory and noticed that it consumed about 1.7GB with heavy use of the GC, I deleted the contents of the directory [C:\Users\Foo\bin\Sencha\Cmd\repo] and the memory footprint has dropped to 1.5/1.6GB, but the speed is identical.

Comment: Is the bad performance reproducible on another machine (PC)?
Do you have a virus scanner installed? Possibly this slows down the build process.

But as I read you post again: What do you actually build? Because you talk about a maven project.
If you are using a "normal" ExtJS workspace, place there your app and packages and then execute the build for the app: how long does this need? 13 minutes?

Comment: Yes, the speed is about the same on all workstations. Only the CI / CD server is even slower. I tried with and without Maven but nothing changes, same speed. The version I use is 6.7.0.63. One note, I have 2 themes and 2 languages, this multiplies the compilation by 4 (absurd). Maven is only used to launch senca.exe along with the Java build which only takes a few seconds ...

Comment: I checked our times for three sencha apps (also built using maven). The first took 1 minute, the second 1:12 and the third 2:12. But all of them were built in testing mode. Depending on the machine and possible garbage collection (we use 3 GB) and the used build mode (e.g. production) and possible definitions regarding the builds options in the app.json possibly the 13 minutes are more or less normal when the application gets built 4 times. 
It seems like there were multiple question regarding this topic in the Sencha forum, but I cannot access the forum anymore, because it was "moved" to SO